# Why do these two find-commands give different results?

Tags: find, ls

I wanted to see all files modified within the last 10 days and who owned them, so I entered the following to give me an idea how many results would be returned;

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -10
```

I then issued the command;

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -10 -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

Both commands give very different result, but I don't understand why. Can someone explain what is going on and why they produce different results?

Comment: Either add `-type f` to list only files, or add `-d` to the `ls` command. Otherwise `ls` will list the directory contents again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you don't use option `-type f`, `find` will return all folders and files. In second command, if a folder is found, command `ls -lh` will list its content, causing more result than first command.

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -10 | wc -l
63
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -10 -exec ls -lh {} \; | wc -l
313
```

You should use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -10

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -10 -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

to list files only.

Comment: what is `1` in end of second find?

Comment: @Babyy: Sorry, mistyping.